# PIC24F programmed but it isn't executing

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm new in PIC MCU. I wrote program for PIC24FJ256JA106 with TFT-320QVT and all were good, but I decided try option "Code protect". I enabled it and at that time I done mistake. I connected programmer VPP/MCLR pin to PIC VDD and ENVREG pins. Also I connected programmer VDD pin to PIC VPP/MCLR pin. After it I tried write a program to PIC but I couldn't. When I connect VDD and VPP pins correct I can write a program to PIC. Nothing happens when I turn on PIC. Before it my program works without any problem.

What's the problem? Code protect or the mistake with VDD, VPP/MCLR pins connect?
I tried disabled code protect but it didn't help.

Pleas, help me! 
Yuriy.

Comment: What do you mean by "LED blinks, but very strange behavior"? By "the last version of your program", do you mean the program just before you set the code protection? Does this program works only but no other program is working?

Comment: Do you have the WDT disabled?

Comment: "LED blinks, but very strange behavior" I mean that blink have do every second, but LED blinks random time. Yes, last version before code protect. Yes, WDT disabled.

Comment: @user45420 I find your question very difficult to understand. I know that English might not be your mother tongue (I am Italian), but please try to edit it and make it clearer because it is impossible to help you now.

Comment: You accidentally reversed the power supply polarity, is that correct? If so, there's a really good chance your chip is blown...

Comment: Yes, I'm Russian. I corrected post and I hope it became more clearer. No, I not reversed the power supply polarity. I reversed VDD and VPP/MCLR pins when I connected PIC to the programmer. I use PICKit2.

Comment: I fixed it. I checked the scheme and found that resistor between VPP/MCLR and VDD has not good connection.